# Updating html text data from jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Suppose I have this:

```
<li id="0">
  <i class="abc"></i>
  TEST TEXT
</li>
```

How could I update "TEST TEXT" with some other string? Using `$("#0").text('NEW TEXT')` removes the i-tag.

Comment: You could probably start by not adding an ID that stars with a number http://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/

Comment: @Ollie yea that was just an example, but good to know

Comment: @Ollie, ID's starting with numbers is ok in HTML5 - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html/18453687#18453687

Comment: @Sergio: this is absolutely true, they are, however, still a pain to select in CSS.

Comment: @DavidThomas, true, good remark.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
$('#0').find('i')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue = 'NEW TEXT';
```

or since it is the last child then:

```
$('#0')[0].lastChild.nodeValue = 'NEW TEXT'; //you can just use document.getElementById
```

or

```
document.getElementById('0').lastChild.nodeValue = 'NEW TEXT';
```

- **[nextSibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nextSibling)**
- **[lastChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.lastChild)**

Answer (score 1):

wrap the "test text" in a span, and replace that.

```
<li id="0">
  <i class="abc"></i>
  <span id="replaceme">TEST TEXT</span>
</li>

$("#replaceme").text('NEW TEXT')
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
$("#0").text(function() {
    $(this).children().html() + "NEW TEXT");
});
```

[Fidle](http://jsfiddle.net/emnSQ/)